# Using lambdaj with String.matches method

Tags: java, hamcrest, lambdaj

How to filter a `Collection<String>` using lambdaj and the String.matches method.
I'm new to lambdaj and feeling dumb since the examples given are more complicated than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, but I'm not happy that it takes this much code to replace a simple for loop.
I prefer "filter" over "select" because it makes the code simpler, and easier to read I think.

```
  public Collection<String> search(String regex) {
    List<String> matches = filter(matches(regex), dictionary);
    return matches;
  }

  static class MatchesMatcher extends TypeSafeMatcher<String> {

    private String regex;

    MatchesMatcher(String regex) {
      this.regex = regex;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matchesSafely(String string) {
      return string.matches(regex);
    }

    public void describeTo(Description description) {
      description.appendText("matches " + regex);
    }

  }

  @Factory
  public static Matcher<String> matches(String regex) {
    return new MatchesMatcher(regex);
  }
```

Comment: Well, it requires that much code *once*. I added a regex matcher to my unit test library, so I don't have to write it again. If I ever use matchers in production code, I'll just move the regex matcher to an appropriate library. As noted in my answer, I'd like to see this matcher in a ready-to-use public library.

Answer (score 2):

If it were possible to do it using the `having(on(...))` construct, the call could look like this:

```
select(collection, having( on(String.class).matches("f*") ))
```

But unfortunately it is not possible, because the `String` class is final and so `on(String.class)` is unable to create the proxy required by the `having` matcher.

Although hamcrest brings no **regex matcher**, you don't have to write your own. The net offers several implementations. I'd like to see such a matcher in a ready-to-use public library, which I could simply include as dependency, instead of having to copy the source code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter a Collection you can do as described below:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Collection<String> collection =  new ArrayList<String>();
    collection.add("foo");
    collection.add("bar");
    collection.add("foo");

    List<String> filtered = select(collection, having(on(String.class), equalTo("foo")));
    assertEquals(2, filtered.size());
}
```

Comment: Thanks...I guess I'm still in disbelief that 1. The syntax is so verbose and 2. I have to write my own matcher to boot, since there appears to be no regex matcher in hamcrest.